Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch when match is confirmed!
I am integrating Google Calendar to my web app using Replit.
I have printed my redirect URI in the Replit console and confirmed that the identical redirect URI is entered in my Google Cloud, after lots of bug checks and confirming my google cloud is set up correctly I am still getting the message: Error 400:redirect_uri_mismatch
Please help, this is driving me mad!
